# Web and database programming with java

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I want to create a Java web application/applet/servlet that does this when the page loads:

Displays "Hello"

Under that, has a box to enter text

Under that, has a button that says OK.

When the user presses OK, I want the text to be saved, and then put into a Microsoft Access database.

This is a vastly simplified version of my real program, but I believe that if I figure out these basic tasks I can complete my actual program. Thanks.

Comment: Try it out and post your code. Then we can help.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea where to start. I have never done any web-based programming in Java, although I consider myself fairly advanced in other areas. Whatever I have tried is able to display "Hello" but nothing else has worked even close to the way I intended to. Also, I do not know how to make the web site accessible to other computers.

Comment: What you are looking for is a tutorial.  Google for 'java applet tutorial' and look there.  Note that the main links use GUI components for the keyboard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [Java Servlet technology](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) from the Java EE 6 tutorial.
It has some examples at the end of each chapter(check the hello2 example at Part II chapter 3).

For the database you can check [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)